# Who can explain the Java operator <<=?

Tags: java

When look into the source codes of Java HashMap,I see some codes below:

while (capacity < initialCapacity)
     capacity <<= 1;

But I can't find the document about operator <<= via Google.I know operator << in Java.
Any help?

Comment: You should accept an answer by ticking the check mark next to the best answer. I assume this is Binyamin Sharet's based on your response to him.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a left shift assignment, it is almost identical to:

```
capacity = capacity << 1;
```

(like `+=` / `-=` / etc.)

Answer (score 3):

It's the same idea as things like `+=`, it shifts and assigns.

In your example, `capacity` will be assigned to itself, left-shifted by one, until it reaches `initialCapacity`. It's on the [operators page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
a <<= b
```

is just a shortcut for left-shift then assign; it's roughly equivalent to:

```
a = a << b;
```

So the line `capacity <<= 1` just means "bitwise shift the value in `capacity` left by 1".

Answer (score 3):

"Shift left equals" ( <<= ) is a technique used to multiply by 2.

The following all produce the same result.

```
while (capacity < initialCapacity) { capacity <<= 1; }

while (capacity < initialCapacity) { capacity = capacity * 2; }

while (capacity < initialCapacity) { capacity *= 2; }
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter02/operators.html

<<=, >>=, >>>=

It is a Shift operations and then assignment, e.g.
    x <<= n;
is equivalent to
    x = x << n;