# What is the "<<=" operator?

Tags: java

I'm a new learner of Java. I have a simple program of using operator just like:

```
public class Test 

    { 
        public static void leftshift(int i, int j) 
        {
            i <<= j; 
        } 
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        {
            int i = 4, j = 2; 
            leftshift(i, j); 


       System.out.printIn(i); 
    } 
}
```

I ran this code, the output is 4.

I know "<<=" is a **Left shift AND assignment operator**. But how does it work?

Comment: That's a [Compound Assignment Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

Comment: no it's not duplicate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656026/who-can-explain-the-java-operator <= this one then? Both explain how it works.

Comment: The issue here is that your function `leftshift` modifies a copy of `i`, not the `i` in `main`. Otherwise `i` would be 16 after than operation.

Comment: What do you mean by "how does it work"? Are you looking for [how java's compiler works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584544/where-is-the-source-code-for-the-java-compiler)?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. If your question is "why does this output 4", then it has nothing to do with `<<=`, it's basic Java - look for Java "pass by value".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This operator

```
X <<= 4;
```

is equivalent to

```
X = X << 4;
```

It follows the same rules as other compound assignment operators.

Answer (score 3):

Its equivalent to

```
i = i << j;
```

Shift the bits representing the value of `i`, by `j` places to the left, and store this new value in `i`

Just like `i += j` is equivalent to:

```
i = i + j;
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it shifts 4 (or `0000 0100`) 2 positions to the left, resulting in 16 ( or `0001 0000`)
being assigned to `i`.

However, this has occurred locally in the `leftshift` method, leaving the variable `i` in `main` with a value of 4.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all of the binary arithmetic/bit operators in Java can be "enhanced" by adding an `=` after the operator.

The expression `someVariable <operator>= someValue;` means the same as `someVariable = someVariable <operator> someValue;`.

So `i <<= j;` means `i = i << j;` which means "Take the value in i, shift left j bits, then store back into i".